# Cannot require parent directory in phpUnit

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a problem with phpUnit.

Whenever I try to open a file using require (or any other similar function) which is not in the same directory or subdirectory as the test file itself, phpUnit throws this error:

> Warning: include_once Failed opening "C:\....." for inclusion (include path = '.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR')

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: Do you know that if a path starts with slash, php will interpret it as starting from local disk root, not from server www root? Maybe that's the problem. If not, post the code.

Answer (score 2):

try using realpath and dirname to get a full path

```
# ../myfolder/file.php 
$path = realpath(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))."/myfolder/file.php"

# ./file.php
$path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__))."/file.php"

# ../file.php
$path = realpath(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))."/file.php"

# ../../file.php
$path = realpath(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))))."/file.php"
```